# Don't know how to enable HTML tags and HTML attributes in Martor

Tags: django, markdown

I'm currently working on integrating [Martor](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor) into my Django project, and I'm having some trouble with the rendering of HTML tags and attributes. Even though I've configured the ALLOWED_HTML_TAGS and ALLOWED_HTML_ATTRIBUTES settings, certain HTML, like `<span style="color: red">I am red</span>`, doesn't render as expected. I've checked the documentation, but there seems to be a lack of information on troubleshooting this specific issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or could provide guidance on how to debug and resolve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.